# How to make a bootable USB drive without software

Tags: usb

I would like to know how to make 2 partitions on a USB drive
1 partition is for backing up files
and the other should be bootable on any system.
then it should just boot a ubuntu.iso (so i can cleanly install ubuntu on my system)
BUT the thing is i would like to have it done without software, for example, if i want to update the iso file (or unpacked on the usb) i would wanne do that by downloading the iso file, extract it there or not even extract it just have it intact, put on the drive in partition 2 and then boot the pc and it should work right away. no hastle with program.
But how?

And how do i change the icons of the 2 partitions, also so that the partitions have the icons on windows. (plus hide the partition which is bootable on both linux and windows)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered [Ventoy](https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html)

Comment: @graham you was faster :)

Comment: I agree with graham Ventoy, I have a 256Gb USB with 25 ISO's that I can use to install. @lucki1000 if you want the rep keep it going ;)

Comment: If UEFI only, you can create one larger FAT32 partition with esp,boot flags & extract ISO into it. Best to use gpt partitioning, but very old MBR even works. Before ventoy, you installed grub, created your own grub.cfg to loopmount ISO and directly booted ISO. I typically have multiple ISO and now use larger SSD as external drive. Can post details, if desired.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you search something like [Ventoy](https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html), after installing this on your USB you can place all the ISOs you wish on the partition, and also store private files, no extraction of ISOs or flashing needed.

It's easy to use:

- Download the executable for your OS(Windows or Linux)
- open it, and install it on your USB stick, before doing that make a backup of all needed private files on your stick
- Now you can mount the "Ventoy" partition and create folders, you can place the ISOs somewhere on the partition, you could like me create a folder for ISOs and one for private
- If Ubuntu releases a new version you can easily put the new ISO in the folder ISOs and delete the old one or keep it.

Comment: I totally agree with this. gparted live ISO, live Ubuntu cinnamon ISO, boot repair ISO are 3 must-haves. I also have debian, fedora, and all other Ubuntu's ready. But a 256Gb stick is full very quick :)  Just 1 warning: not all ISO work. Every so often the ISO just crashes. And sometimes I need to put it back on the ISO or even re-doiwnload for it to work.

Comment: @Rinzwind I now what you're talking about the ISO crashing. It is crazy. You would think like the ISO wants to be buggy and broken even before you install it. Recently installed Ubuntu on a PC and what do you think? Doesn't boot.

Answer (score 1):

### Simple Hand Made USB with Optional Persistence

Making a Grub2 booter that can use Persistent partitions is easy.*

- Boot Installed Ubuntu or Live USB.
- Insert Target USB.
- Start GParted.
- Create a GPT partition table on Target USB.
- Create a 1MB BIOS boot partition on the left, formatted as unformatted.
- Add a 300MB FAT32 EFI boot partition next to it.
- Add an ext4 root partition large enough for the Ubuntu ISO's contents, (~ 5GB for 22.04).
- Create an ext4 partition labeled casper-rw or writable (optional)
- Add a NTFS or FAT32 data partition if desired.
- Apply all operations.
- Flag partition 1 bios_grub.
- Flag Partition 2 boot, esp
- Close GParted.

[image: gparted]

- Open the ISO's folder as Administrator, open the ISO using Archive Manager.
- Extract the ISO's contents to the Target's root partition.
- Drag and drop the boot and EFI folders from Archive Manager window to the EFI boot partition.
- Edit sdx2/boot/grub/grub.cfg adding set root=(hd0,3) after the first line that starts with `menuentry`.
- Add a space and the word "persistent" after ---.

[image: grub.cfg]

- Install grub, if in BIOS mode or booted from USB drive run:

  ```
    sudo mount /dev/sdx2 /mnt

    sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sdx
  ```
- If in UEFI mode on installed system, boot into the Target drive and run the above.

Answer (score -1):

You can directly write a ISO image to a USB stick using the `Disk Image Writer` tool.

Open "Files" application and navigate to your ISO. Right click and choose the option which says "Open With" and out of the options choose `Disk Image Writer`. You will see something like this:

[image: Disk Image Writer]

Now, in the `Destination` drop down, choose the USB stick you want to write your ISO too. Finally, press `Start Restoring`.

You will now have a USB stick with only one ISO and that you can boot  into right as the computer turns on.

***Edit**: You might see something like "The ISO file is **** smaller than the destination. Don't worry, that is okay. Just continue and press `Start Restoring`.*